# How to send value from activity to interface query in android retrofit

Tags: android, rest, authentication, retrofit2

Hello I am currently creating an android app. I have a login, so when the user is logged I want to pass the email string to the retrofit GET method. Because by using email I make other calls that are specific to that user.

```
My Activity looks like this:


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        txt=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        reservationList=new ArrayList<>();

        //http://10.0.2.2:8081/profile/details/ + email
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8081/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MyAPICall myAPICall = retrofit.create(MyAPICall.class);
        Call<Profile> call = myAPICall.getProfile(email);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Profile>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Profile> call, Response<Profile> response) {

                if(response.code() != 200){
                    txt.setText("Check the connection");
                    return;
                }

                //Get Data into Textview
                String jsony="";


                jsony = " First Name:            " + response.body().getFirstname() +
                        "\n Second Name:       " + response.body().getSecondname()+
                        "\n Birthdate:              "+ response.body().getBirthdate()+
                        "\n Credit Card:           " + response.body().getCreditcard()+
                        "\n Telephone :           " + response.body().getTelephone() +
                        "\n Email:                     " + response.body().getEmail();

             
                txt.append(jsony);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Profile> call, Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
```

GET method in my interface looks like this:

```
public interface MyAPICall {
    

    @GET("profile/details/email")

    Call<Profile> getProfile(@Query("email")String email);

}
```

I tried using @Query but I can see it's wrong. How can I get it right please?

Answer (score 2):

Change your endpoint look like this

```
 @GET("profile/details/{email}")
```

Because when we use query param we need to add that key inside Curley Brackett {}

Comment: Isn't there anything wrong in the call Call<Profile> call = myAPICall.getProfile(email);
from the activity?

Comment: it still gives me error

Comment: whats the error and try to print complete link

Comment: and also add slash before start endpoint /profile/details/email

Comment: @TefDon pls accept answer it its work for you